# Struct in C + Malloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc

I have this  [UPDATED]

```
typedef struct Cerchi { 
    char nome[4];
    int x; //coordinate centro
    int y; //coordinate centro
    int r; //raggio
}cerchio;

   cerchio *leggi_file ( FILE *fp)
{
            char buffer[100]; 
            int i=0;    
            cerchio *bufcer;
            bufcer=(cerchio *)malloc(sizeof (int)*10000000);               
                while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)!= NULL) //Fino a che file non è null
                         {  
                         //bufcer=realloc(bufcer, sizeof(int)*100);
                         sscanf(buffer, "%s %d %d %d",bufcer[i].nome,&bufcer[i].x,&bufcer[i].y,&bufcer[i].r);
        /*stampa di controllo*/          printf("\n%s %d %d %d",bufcer[i].nome,bufcer[i].x,bufcer[i].y,bufcer[i].r); 
                         i++;                
                         }
                         return bufcer;
                
                                          
}
```

This function is working.
That's the UPDATED main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Mancano parametri da tastiera\n"); //Sempre >=1 parametri passati
    exit(1);
}
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Impossibile aprire il file\n");
    exit(1);
}
    struct Cerchi *bufcer = NULL;
bufcer = leggi_file(fp);
stampa(bufcer); 
//vettore = leggi_file(FILE *fp);    E R R O R E
fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

I'm not able to print my *bufcer struct in this function

```
    void stampa(bufcer)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<50;i++)
 {
 printf("\n%s %d %d %d",bufcer[i]->nome,bufcer[i]->x,bufcer[i]->y,bufcer[i]->r); 
 }
}
```

Please try to help me, tomorrow morning I have an exam about it
[UPDATED]
Which error I'm doing? Can you try to solve it and help me?
Thanks a lot...

Comment: `bufcer=(cerchio *)malloc(sizeof (int)*10000000);`  Why `sizeof(int)`?  Shouldn't that be `sizeof(cerchio)`?

Comment: Please **learn** the basics of the language before trying to write programs in it. You wouldn't try to speak e. g. Russian if you have never learnt it, would you?

Comment: You malloc a `buffer` in `leggi_file`, return it, forget to store it in `main`, and expect to print it in `stampa`. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: I have to do Realloc function because there are 22 Line obtained (And 22 data in struct too) from a txt block , btw the first problem was that i can't pass the struct , so realloc become My problem and i don't want to ask to anyone something about that and i solved like that >.<

Byako ; I malloc a vector of struct in the function

Comment: You have ignored the return value from `*leggi_file()`. But right after you try to use it with `stampa( struct Cerchi *bufcer);` which is trying to use a variable which is neither accessible, or still in scope. Oops @byako you already said it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `->` operator when accessing `structure` elements, so your `printf` will be as

`printf("\n%s %d %d %d",bufcer[i]->nome,bufcer[i]->x,bufcer[i]->y,bufcer[i]->r);`

Also, `->` operator use for `scanf()`

You need to pass `&` of structure to pass structure pointer

Comment: programma2.c:18:76: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ 
programma2.c: In function ‘main’:
programma2.c:50:10: error: expected expression before ‘struct’
  stampa( struct Cerchi *bufcer);

Comment: How you are passing structure pointer ? You need to pass address of structure. Please check below link to understand structure pointers : https://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-passing-struct-to-function/

Answer (score 0):

1. [Do not cast return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
2. Always check the return value of `sscanf()` to ensure all the elements got scanned successfully.
3. Change `stampa( struct Cerchi *bufcer);` to `stampa(bufcer);` This is a function call not a function definition or declaration. Also, add `struct Cerchi *bufcer = NULL;` inside `main()` before calling `stampa()`.
4. You are not using the return value of `leggi_file ()`. As per your logic, you need to collect the value in `bufcer`. Change your code to

   ```
   bufcer = leggi_file(fp);
   ```
5. Always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Comment: The return of sscanf is correct ; 
Now i have this error : programma2.c: In function ‘main’:
programma2.c:50:9: error: ‘bufcer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  stampa(bufcer); 

How to take it from void return?

Comment: *please* read our comments. You need to store the value returned by `leggi_file` when you call it in `main`: the variable `bufcer` in `leggi_file` is out of scope in main. Try `struct Cerchi *bufcer = leggi_file();`, but you should really read a C tutorial.

Comment: @byako Thank you, most valuable information. added that in my answer itself. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh i read at all , if you look at updated code :\ I make everything u say me to do i think ...
You mean to remove Void before stampa(bufcer) ?